# Receiving PG::GroupingError While Trying to Aggregate all post with votes greater than 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I tried 4 different SQL algorithms to group posts by cached votes with totals greater than 0 and the photo column must not be nil.

My last attempt is below.

```
@popular_user_photos = Post.where.not('posts.photo' => nil).having('cached_votes_total > 0').order(created_at: :desc).last(20)
```

I receive the error below.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "posts.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE ("p...
```

Comment: If `cached_votes_total` is a column then wouldn't you use `where('cached_votes_total > 0')` instead of `having`?

Comment: That definitely worked. I'll post the correct format/solution below.

Answer (score 0):

The corrected SQL statement is

```
@popular_user_photos = Post.where.not('posts.photo' => nil).where('cached_votes_total > 0').order(created_at: :desc).last(20)
```